# Building and publishing a .NET framework solution with multiple functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a pipeline that deploys multiple azure function apps. In solution below you can see structure:

[image]

At the moment I am at this stage in the pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '365Governance.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Building solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
```

But the publish gives following warning:
[image]

Any one has a sample of a YAML that deploys a version 1 azure function app or can provide some feedback why this does not produce any outputs? I properly need to specify each azure function app project or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need add task [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) before task `PublishBuildArtifacts` to copy files from a source folder to a target folder using match patterns. Then we can publish the construction under the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) directory.

Sample: Copy all files from the source directory

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Result:

[image]